# C# Get all records from Web API where pagination is implemented

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-core, ienumerable, webapi

My requirement is accessing a third party Web API, which has total of 120 records (just an example - it can be more). The Api has pagination implemented which returns default 50 records based on page number. By passing {Page} in parameters, we can get other 50 records for that page number:

Example :

```
https://www.thirdpartapi.com/users?Page=1

https://www.thirdpartapi.com/users?Page=2
```

This is the response from API -

```
{
 "total" : 120,
 "users" : [
     {
        "id" : "abc123",
        "firstName" : "First1",
        "lastName" : "Last1"
     },
     {
        "id" : "abc124",
        "firstName" : "First2",
        "lastName" : "Last2"
     },
     ...... 50 users
  ]
}
```

I want to get all 120 users records from the Web API.

this is my Response model:

```
public class ApiResponse
{
     public int total { get; set; }
     public List<Users> users { get; set; }
     public ApiResponse()
     {
         users = new List<Users>();
     }
}

public class Users
{
     public string id { get; set; }
     public string firstName { get; set; }
     public string lastName{ get; set; } 
}
```

I am making a recursive call to the WebAPI to get all the 120 records:

```
List<Users> = (List<Users>)CallApi();

private List<Users> CallApi(int? pageNumber = 1)
{        
    var response = webmanager.RestApi("https://www.thirdpartapi.com/users?Page={pageNumber}");
    
    ApiResponse data = (ApiResponse)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response, typeOf(ApiResponse));

    if(data.users.Count > 0)
    { 
        data.users.AddRange((IEnumberable<Users>)CallApi(pageNumber + 1));
        return data.users;
    }
    else
        return data.users;
 }
```

I am able to get all the Users (120). But is this an optimal way to call an API? Please suggest a better solution.

Comment: It's paginated because they *don't* want you to fetch everything at once. Unless they expose a way to request it all, iterating the pages is likely the best approach available to you.

Comment: Note that generally a page number *is not* a paging API but rather a loose display concept (unless querying immutable data). It is better to use API that returns some sort of continuation token to query *next* items instead of "items that are currently on page 3"... but that's not a useful opinion on how to call that particular API.

Comment: does the API take a "results per page" value?

Comment: @pcalkins - Yes, the API also takes "PageSize" int value and its default is 50 results per page if no value passed

Answer (score 2):

Since its a third party API, calling the API multiple times is the only option. Just a minor suggestion would be to keep track of the count of records fetched and check if it's greater than the total count. Here you could avoid the 4th API call if you do so.